# Splunk: Execute the same query on multiple datasources

Tags: database, splunk, splunk-query, dbconnect, splunk-hec

i have multiple dabatases (>100) with the identic structure.
For business-monitoring, i have about 80 queries which check information in the database.
Now, i want to execute each of this queries on each of this databases and load the result into splunk.
In splunk, is it possible to define the >100 database-connections once and the 80 queries once and then make some "magic" step to execute each statement on each database?
I don't want to create a new connection for each combination of database and query.

Answer (score 1):

The only way Splunk has to connect to a database "itself" is via [DB Connect](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2686/#/details) ([docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DBX/3.3.1/DeployDBX/AboutSplunkDBConnect))

*From Splunk's perspective*, there is no way to connect to 100 databases without having unique connections to each.

So far as I know, there is no tool that will connect to more than one database without unique connections - that's something database servers enforce in transactional models.

That being said, if you have a way to enumerate all the databases you want to connect to, and a place to save the queries you want to run, you could build either a

- [scripted-input](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/AdvancedDev/ScriptedInputsIntro) add-on that could use your language of choice (whatever's available on the Splunk server(s)/endpoint(s) it's running on) to iterate through each database, run each query, and ship the results back to Splunk, or
- in similar fashion to the scripted-input option, write a script (or set of scripts) that would execute the queries in question against the databases you're targeting, and submit results to the [HTTP Event Collector](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Data/HECExamples) ([HEC](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/httpeventcollector/)) (HL has a great write-up on HEC over [here](https://www.hurricanelabs.com/splunk-tutorials/how-to-set-up-splunk-hec-the-right-way), and here's George Starcher's [Python class](https://github.com/georgestarcher/Splunk-Class-httpevent) for HEC)